# When to add salt in sourdough bread mix?

Tags: sourdough

I was reading around and seems that a lot of forums are saying to delay adding the salt in your sourdough mix.

I dissolved the salt in water and then I poured the sourdough starter in the water and gave it a light stir and then I poured them in the flower and mix them all together. Did I just killed the yeast? Will my bread still rise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The salt doesn't kill the yeast but slows it down. As well as lacto bacteria producing the acidity.

There's even a name for the conscious adding of salt to the sourdough in German: [Monheimer Salzsauer-Verfahren](https://www.baeckerlatein.de/monheimer-salzsauer-verfahren/) ([in English](https://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?depth=1&nv=1&rurl=translate.google.com&sp=nmt4&tl=en&u=https://www.baeckerlatein.de/monheimer-salzsauer-verfahren/&xid=17259,15700022,15700122,15700124,15700149,15700168,15700186,15700190,15700201&usg=ALkJrhiS6V5gIyXozDqHv_KBvG5nO3RZ8Q)):

> The salt inhibits yeasts and acid formation. The maturation is delayed
>   with intensification of the aromas. At the same time, the processing
>   properties of the dough (influencing the proteins) improve. The bread
>   gets a balanced taste with fine pores of the crumb .
>
> Especially for the hobby bakery, this type of guide is suitable to
>   produce breads with a balanced, mild flavor and flavor, without
>   complicated and time-consuming work processes (as in the classic
>   three-step guidance ).

Answer (score 2):

As above, salt is inherently necessary, but when you add the salt is important, add the salt to your flour, then add the starter/water mixture, then mix. This way the salt won't immediately impair your starter. Too much salt will kill your starter. If you follow the quantities of your recipe, it will not kill it, but retard it sufficiently while also promoting gluten formation. Salt should always be 1-2% in relation to total flour quantity (if 1000g of flour, 10-20g of salt).